# VBA: Colouring chart series by name only if series exists

Tags: excel, vba

Fairly new to VBA, I am trying to loop through all charts in an excel file and apply some formatting on them. Some of the formatting will be applied to all charts such as font family and chart background colour.

Where I have a problem is setting up an if condition whereby the VBA code only tries to apply a colour to a series if the series name is in the chart. At the moment it is not changing the colour.

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate
    Dim ch As Chart
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Font.Name = "Flexo"
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Interior.Color = RGB(227, 228, 234)
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Interior.Color = RGB(227, 228, 234)
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
    With ActiveChart
    nSrs = .SeriesCollection.Count
    For iSrs = 1 To nSrs
        ' only format series whose names are found
        Select Case LCase$(.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Name)
            Case "Erneuerbare" '******CHANGE HERE******
                .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Interior.Color = RGB(136, 187, 60)
         End Select
    Next
   End With
  Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: IIRC, you want to use: `.Format.Fill.ForeColor`. `FullSeriesCollection` may also be the collection you want to use. If that's not the problem, have you verified that the series actually exists using debug.print or a similar method? Maybe there's a space at the start or end of the series name?

Comment: You're using `Select Case LCase$(.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Name)` but the value you're testing "Erneuerbare" is not lower-case